# C# Run a procedure without specifying a parameter name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

How can I execute a stored procedure that takes in parameters without having to specify the prameters name? The name of the parameter in the stored procedure may change from CustomerID to CustID so I don't want to have to keep changing my code.

Rather than doing what is provided below where you specify the parameter name -

```
command.Parameters.Add("@dtStart", SqlDbType.DateTime);
command.Parameters["@dtStart"].Value = startDate;
command.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", SqlDbType.NChar);
command.Parameters["@CustomerID"].Value = customerID;
```

I am looking to do something like this -

```
command.Parameters.Add(startDate, customerID);
```

Comment: Just curious, does the SP still work if you don't set the name of the parameters?  If you need to modify the Value after creation, you can reference them by their index: 0, 1, etc.  You would of course have to change your code if they reordered the parameters of the SP.

Comment: Had a talk and they decided not to switch parameter name anymore so the traditional way works for me at the moement. At first, I was looking for a solution where you can use index similar to what you stated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> The name of the parameter in the stored procedure may change from CustomerID to CustID

Slap the person who does that.

Parameter names are your reliable way of identifying a parameter. The other option is sequence, seems a lot more flaky.

Comment: Agreed! but some time in such application we get kind of requirement where we just need to send values in sequence of respective parameter. and as work around we have to use "exec" and write stored procedure name with parameters in command text

Comment: Coming from land of gandhi i will recommend a non violent approach and no physical violence. Do a non violent candle march instead.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can create a `SqlParameter` object without specifying its name. However, you should be able to use the `DeriveParameters` method ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx)) to get a collection of parameters with the names automatically retreived from the SQL server.

You can find an [example here](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/11/01/SqlCommandBuilderDeriveParameters.aspx). It looks roughly like this:

```
SqlCommand command = // create a command for calling the stored procedure
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);

// Now you can set values of parameters in a loop
for(int i = 0; i < command.Parameters.Length; i++) {
  var parameter = command.Parameters[i]
  // Set value of ith parameter
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a nameless SQL parameter if you force its name to null or empty *after* it's been added to the Parameters collection, something like this:

```
var par = cmd.CreateParameter();
par.Value = myValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(par); // this will change the name to "ParameterX"
par.ParameterName = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameter Discovery, scroll down on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664692(PandP.50).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using Unnamed parameters is only possible with [OdbcCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.aspx) and [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.aspx) object parameters.

Answer (score -2):

You could use SQL's `exec`, which does not ask for parameter names:

```
command.CommandText = string.Format(
    "exec dbo.YourProcedure {0}, '{1}'",
    intParameter,
    stringParameter.Replace("'","''")
);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If your parameter source is untrustworthy, be sure to escape single quotes in string parameters.  It's done for `stringParameter` in the snippet above.